# Javascript check if two objects are of equal lengths for all keys

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have two mappings:

```
const mapOne = {idOne: ['a', 'b'], idTwo: ['c', 'd', 'e']};
const mapTwo = {idOne: [1, 2], idTwo: [3, 4, 5]};
```

It should return true since both `idOne` has length 2 and `idTwo` has length 3. I tried doing:

```
const b = Object.entries(mapOne).map((k, v) => v.length === mapTwo[k].length);
```

But it's saying k is not defined and also it would return an array of boolean instead of a single boolean.

Comment: replace `map` with `every` and instead of `(k, v)` do `([k, v])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` and check if each of the [key, value] entries has equal length in both objects.

The main problem in your code was that you should have written `([k,v])` instead of `(k,v)`. Then, you need to use `every` instead of `map`.

```js
const mapOne = {idOne: ['a', 'b'], idTwo: ['c', 'd', 'e']};
const mapTwo = {idOne: [1, 2], idTwo: [3, 4, 5]};

const result = Object.entries(mapOne)
  .every(([k, {length}]) => mapTwo[k].length===length)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger ah, thanks, I pasted in the wrong thing